# Greek letters in pgfplotstable table

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, greek

trying to create a table using pgfplotstable, but I'm having errors when I want to write Greek letters (actually, any math mode symbol starting with '\'). Where I have 'a' and 'b' I would like to have an alpha and a beta. Can you help me?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,pgfplotstable}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{0,71,171}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{gray}{0.92}

\newcommand{\topline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{0.1em}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}

\newcommand{\midtopline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}

\newcommand{\bottomline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor} %
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowbottomsep}}%

\newcommand{\midheader}[2]{%
    \midrule\topmidheader{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\topmidheader[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textsc{#2}}\\%
            \addlinespace[0.5ex]}

\pgfplotstableset{mystyle/.style ={%
    header=true,
    string type,
    column type=c,
    every odd row/.style={
        before row=
    },       
    every first column/.style={
        column type=l
    },        
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\topline\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}},
        after row={\midtopline},
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomline
    },
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\
 }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[mystyle]{
    {$ $}        & {$a$}                 &  {$b$} \\
    {0}        & {10}                &  {$1000$}\\     
    }
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Probably [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124873/121799) is related. (I am not saying your question is a duplicate.)

Comment: or see example on the top of page 17, documentation for `pgfplotstable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zarko noted, the example shown on pages 17-18 of the manual  for `pgfplotstable`makes use of one of the possible solutions to your problem.

The format used is explained at the end of page 11 in the same manual:

> `columns/{lowlevel colname}/.style={column name = display column name}`
>   Here, lowlevel colname refers to the column name that is present in your input table. This lowlevel
>   column name has a couple of restrictions (it has to be expandable, for example - that means many control
>   sequences are forbidden). The value of column name is only used within `\pgfplotstabletypeset` in
>   order to generate a display name for the column in question.

I have included the solution to your question below, and the result obtained after compilation. You will find my modifications in the `[< options >]` of `\pgfplotstabletypeset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,pgfplotstable}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{0,71,171}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{gray}{0.92}

\newcommand{\topline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{0.1em}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}

\newcommand{\midtopline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor}}

\newcommand{\bottomline}{ %
    \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
    \arrayrulecolor{rulecolor} %
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowbottomsep}}%

\newcommand{\midheader}[2]{%
    \midrule\topmidheader{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\topmidheader[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textsc{#2}}\\%
            \addlinespace[0.5ex]}

\pgfplotstableset{mystyle/.style ={%
    header=true,
    string type,
    column type=c,
    every odd row/.style={
        before row=
    },       
    every first column/.style={
        column type=l
    },        
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\topline\rowcolor{tableheadcolor}},
        after row={\midtopline},
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomline
    },
    col sep=&,
    row sep=\\
 }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[mystyle, 
    columns/a/.style={column name=$\alpha$},
    columns/b/.style={column name=$\beta$},
]{
    {$ $}        & {a}                 &  {b} \\
    {0}        & {10}                &  {$1000$}\\     
    }
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]